# Update react-big-calendar component when new event created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-big-calendar

I am using react-big-calendar and wish to give the user the ability to create a new event when they drag the mouse over the calendar to select a date/time range as per the [create events demonstration](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#selectable).

However the code I have written does not re-render the component on successful event creation.  The user is able to create a new event and it will be displayed if the user selects another view (e.g. Agenda) - and will then be present in all views.  However it does not display immediately in the current view as per the demo.

I'm fairly sure the answer to this lies in useEffect; but I'm going round in circles trying to figure it out.

```
import React, { useState  } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'

function MyCalendar() {
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)
    const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState([]);

    function handleSelect ({ start, end }) {
        const title = window.prompt('New Event name')
        if (title) {
            var newEvent = {
                start: start,
                end: end,
                title: title 
            }
            let updateEventsList = eventsList;
            updateEventsList.push(newEvent);
            setEventsList(updateEventsList);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
        <Calendar
        selectable
        defaultView="week"
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        localizer={localizer}
        events={eventsList}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        style={{ height: 500 }}
        onSelectSlot={handleSelect}
        />
        </div>
    )
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
        <MyCalendar />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add your 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css' and 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css' files?

Comment: I want to help you, but It is hard to understand what is going on without css :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've copied and pasted the CSS to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/p3bsYPQS

Comment: Ok, I will try to solve your problem

Comment: Appreciate your help, I don't think it is CSS related; but then if I knew I wouldn't be asking!

Comment: Does my snippet work fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React doesn't like mutatiton and because of it your code worked wrong.

You need to change your function

```
  function handleSelect({ start, end }) {
    const title = window.prompt("New Event name");
    if (title) {
      var newEvent = {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        title: title
      };
      setEventsList([...eventsList, newEvent]);
    }
  }
```

In this function I only changed these strings

```
let updateEventsList = eventsList;
updateEventsList.push(newEvent);
setEventsList(updateEventsList);
```

And I did it so

```
setEventsList([...eventsList, newEvent]);
```

Comment: It better use concat or rest parametr in react

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I spent ages messing around with useEffect; barking up completely wrong tree.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If you will have some questions you can write to me here and I will try to help you :) I like your project